# stream analytics query to get EnqueuedTime device_id from device data

Tags: sql, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to write Stream analytics query to push iothub data to SQL database.

MY IOTHUB data as follows.

```
{
    "Device_Id":"P371602011",
    "kWL1":11.683551775144204,
    "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2017-12-28T07:21:14.3829760Z",
    "PartitionId":0,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2017-12-28T07:21:04.6660000Z",
    "IoTHub":
    {
        "MessageId":null,
        "CorrelationId":null,
        "ConnectionDeviceId":"iotclient",
        "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId":"636500361000571958",
        "EnqueuedTime":"2017-12-28T07:21:04.0540000Z",
        "StreamId":null
    }
}
```

Now i am trying to write Device_Id, kWL1 and EnqueuedTime to SQL database. My Stream analytics query looks like below.

```
SELECT
Device_Id AS PowerScout,
IoTHub.EnqueuedTime AS [ReadingTime],
kWL1 AS [kW L1]
INTO
[DataBase]
FROM
[IoTHub]
```

When i run Stream analytics job, i can see Device_Id and kWL1 Values but EnqueuedTime is showing as NULL.
How to get EnqueuedTime from IOTHub Data.

```
{
"DeviceData": [
    {
        "Device_Id": "5",
        "AMPSL1": 1.2515641182178531E-38
   }
],
"EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-01-08T05:03:08.0840000Z",
"IoTHub": {
    "MessageId": null,
    "CorrelationId": null,
    "ConnectionDeviceId": "VHW1",
    "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636509839893748612",
    "EnqueuedTime": "2018-01-08T05:03:06.7460000Z",
    "StreamId": null
}
}
```

How can i get Device_Id and AMPSL1 in above format.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to make it with the help of @Michael Xu - MSFT. The final query looks below.

```
WITH DeviceDataCollection AS 
( 
     SELECT GetArrayElement(DeviceData,0)as DeviceData, 
     IoTHub.EnqueuedTime as time FROM IoTHubIn     
) 
SELECT 
     DeviceData.Device_Id AS PowerScout,
     time AS [TimeStamp]
INTO
[DataBase]
FROM 
[DeviceDataCollection]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your provided infomation, I think the problem is that the name **IoTHub** is dumplicate, one is *inputs* in your Stream Analytics,but meanwhile the *IoTHub* is an object in your data.You can modify the name as ***IoTHubMessageContent***(for example, you can change it to other name) in your data such as following.

```
{
   "Device_Id":"P371602011",
   "kWL1":11.683551775144204,
   "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2017-12-28T07:21:14.3829760Z",
   "PartitionId":0,
   "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2017-12-28T07:21:04.6660000Z",
   "IoTHubMessageContent":
   {
       "MessageId":null,
       "CorrelationId":null,
       "ConnectionDeviceId":"iotclient",
       "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId":"636500361000571958",
       "EnqueuedTime":"2017-12-28T07:21:04.0540000Z",
       "StreamId":null
   }
}
```

And then modify the query as following.

```
SELECT
Device_Id AS PowerScout,
IoTHubMessageContent.EnqueuedTime AS [ReadingTime],
kWL1 AS [kW L1]
INTO
[DataBase]
FROM
[IoTHub]
```

After that,when executing the query command, the result will come.

[image]

Comment: {
    "DeviceData": [
        {
            "Device_Id": "5",
            "AMPSL1": 1.2515641182178531E-38
        }
    ],
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-01-08T05:03:08.0840000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
        "MessageId": null,
        "CorrelationId": null,
        "ConnectionDeviceId": "VHW1",
        "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636509839893748612",
        "EnqueuedTime": "2018-01-08T05:03:06.7460000Z",
        "StreamId": null
    }
}

How can i get Device_Id & AMPSL1 in above Format?

Comment: @krishnabh, please refer to this blog([Handling Json array in Stream Analytics Query](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2016/02/23/handling-json-array-in-stream-analytics-query/)). I think it will be helpful for you. You can try this query command:

WITH DeviceDataCollection AS
(
SELECT
GetArrayElement(DeviceData,0)as DeviceData 
FROM input 
)

SELECT
DeviceData.Device_Id,
DeviceData.AMPSL1
FROM DeviceDataCollection

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thank you for Quick reply, i tried this one already, using this i can get Device_Id & AMPSL1, but i am missing other values like IoTHub.EnqueuedTime AS [TimeStamp] in the same query. Is there any way i can get device_Id & AMPSL1 and EnqueuedTime

Comment: Please try this query command: WITH DeviceDataCollection 
    AS ( 
        SELECT GetArrayElement(DeviceData,0) as DeviceData ,
        Iothub.EnqueuedTime
        FROM input 
        ) 
SELECT DeviceData.Device_Id, DeviceData.AMPSL1 , EnqueuedTime
FROM DeviceDataCollection

Comment: Finally i created query as below.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to modify your query as follow to be able to read the nested JSON object called IoTHub in the IoTHub input:

```
SELECT
Device_Id AS PowerScout,
[IoTHub].[IoTHub].EnqueuedTime AS [ReadingTime],
kWL1 AS [kW L1]
INTO
[DataBase]
FROM
[IoTHub]
```